# trying to remove nested object using lodash

Tags: object, redux, lodash

i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong but i am not able to unset. im trying to remove an item from an object in redux. tried to use delete but it breaks the app. i get a true response from lodash that it has been deleted but when i console after it shows the same object.

```
let newState = {...state};
console.log('before', newState);
console.log(_.unset(newState, [`year2020.month${action.month}.days.day${action.day}`]));
console.log('after',newState);
return newState;
```

sample state:

```
let state = {
  year2020: {
    month3: {
      num: 0,
      name: "January",
      length: 31,
      starts: 3,
      days: {
        day1: { mood: 1 },
        day2: { mood: 2 },
        day3: { mood: 3 },
        day11: { mood: 4 }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your path is a string (one string separated by dots), don't wrap in an array.

Note: use `_.cloneDeep()` instead of shallow clone (spread), since you mutate deeper levels of the object:

```js
const state = {"year2020":{"month3":{"num":0,"name":"January","length":31,"starts":3,"days":{"day1":{"mood":1},"day2":{"mood":2},"day3":{"mood":3},"day11":{"mood":4}}}}};

const newState = _.cloneDeep(state);
const action = { payload: { month: 3, day: 1 }};
_.unset(newState, `year2020.month${action.payload.month}.days.day${action.payload.day}`);
console.log('after',newState);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Lodash/fp plays nicely with redux, since it doesn't mutate the original object (in this example, the path is array):

```js
const state = {"year2020":{"month3":{"num":0,"name":"January","length":31,"starts":3,"days":{"day1":{"mood":1},"day2":{"mood":2},"day3":{"mood":3},"day11":{"mood":4}}}}};

const action = { payload: { month: 3, day: 1 }};

const newState = _.unset([
  'year2020',
  `month${action.payload.month}`,
  'days',
  `day${action.payload.day}`
], state);

console.log('after',newState);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: You're welcome, and I'm glad that you've learned something :)